# Why component scanning does not work for Spring Boot unit tests?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

The service class `FooServiceImpl` is annotated with [@Service](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) aka `@Component` which makes it eligible for autowiring. Why this class is not being picked up and autowired during unit tests?

```
@Service
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
    @Override
    public String reverse(String bar) {
        return new StringBuilder(bar).reverse().toString();
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@SpringBootTest
public class FooServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;
    @Test
    public void reverseStringShouldReverseAnyString() {
        String reverse = fooService.reverse("hello");
        assertThat(reverse).isEqualTo("olleh");
    }
}
```

The test failed to load application context,

```
2018-02-08T10:58:42,385 INFO    Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [io.github.thenilesh.service.impl.FooServiceTest], using DelegatingSmartContextLoader
2018-02-08T10:58:42,393 INFO    Could not detect default resource locations for test class [io.github.thenilesh.service.impl.FooServiceTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml}.
2018-02-08T10:58:42,394 INFO    Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [io.github.thenilesh.service.impl.FooServiceTest]: FooServiceTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
2018-02-08T10:58:42,432 INFO    Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, (...)org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
2018-02-08T10:58:42,448 INFO    Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@f0ea28, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@16efaab,(...)org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@9604d9]
2018-02-08T10:58:42,521 INFO    Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@173f9fc: startup date [Thu Feb 08 10:58:42 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-08T10:58:42,606 INFO    JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-02-08T10:58:42,666 ERROR    Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@19aaa5] to prepare test instance [io.github.thenilesh.service.impl.FooServiceTest@57f43]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'io.github.thenilesh.service.impl.FooServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fooService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'io.github.thenilesh.service.FooService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    . . . 
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'io.github.thenilesh.service.FooService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 28 more
2018-02-08T10:58:42,698 INFO    Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@173f9fc: startup date [Thu Feb 08 10:58:42 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```

[Full stack trace](https://gist.github.com/TheNilesh/3bb6cf7bef40d1706d9d939118f66886)

If test class is annotated with [@SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) then it creates whole application context including database connection and a lot of unrelated beans which obviously not needed for this unit test(It won't be *unit* test then!). What is expected is that only beans on which `FooService` depends should be instantiated, except which are mocked, with `@MockBean`.

Comment: Have you tried @SpringBootTest(classes=FooServiceImpl.class)?

Comment: The fact that you need a context already makes it an integration test. If you want a unit test just create an instance of the repository, mock the dependencies and be done. As soon as you need a context it is an integration test.

Comment: @Justas Your comment should be an answer, along with 'Explanation of Spring Boot component scanning in unit test'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `@SpringBootTest(classes=FooServiceImpl.class)`.

As it's mentioned on [Annotation Type SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html):

> public abstract Class<?>[] classes
>
> The annotated classes to use for loading an ApplicationContext. Can
> also be specified using @ContextConfiguration(classes=...). If no
> explicit classes are defined the test will look for nested
> @Configuration classes, before falling back to a
> SpringBootConfiguration search.
>
> Returns:
> the annotated classes used to load the application context See Also:
> ContextConfiguration.classes()
>
> Default:
> {}

This would load only necessary class. If don't specify, it may load a database configuration and other stuff which would make your test slower.

On the other hand, if you want really want unit test, you can test this code without Spring - then `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest` annotations are not necessary. You can test `FooServiceImpl` instance. If you have `Autowired`/injected properties or services, you set them via setters, constructors or mock with [Mockito](https://dzone.com/articles/a-guide-to-mocking-with-mockito).

Answer (score 2):

I had to solve a similar problem with a slight variation. Thought to share the details of that, thinking it might give choices to those who hit upon similar issues.

I wanted to write integration tests with only necessary dependencies loaded up instead of all of the app dependencies. So I chose to use `@DataJpaTest`, instead of `@SpringBootTest`. And, I had to include `@ComponentScan` too to parse the @Service beans. However, the moment ServiceOne started using a mapper bean from another package, I had to specify the specific packages to be loaded with `@ComponentScan`. Surprisingly, I even had to do this for the second service that does not auto-wire this mapper. I did not like that because it leaves the impression to the reader that this service depends on that mapper when it is actually not. So I realized that the package structure for services needs to be fine-tuned further to represent the dependencies more accurately.

To summarise, instead of @SpringBootTest, a combination of @DataJpaTest+@ComponentScan with package names can use to load just the layer-specific dependencies. This might even help us to fine-tune the design to represent your dependencies more accurately.

#### Design before

**1. com.java.service.ServiceOneImpl**

```
@Service
public class ServiceOneImpl implements ServiceOne {   
  @Autowired
  private RepositoryOne repositoryOne;    
  @Autowired
  private ServiceTwo serviceTwo;      
  @Autowired
  private MapperOne mapperOne;
}
```

**2. com.java.service.ServiceTwoImpl**

```
@Service
public class ServiceTwoImpl implements ServiceTwo {   
  @Autowired
  private RepositoryTwo repositoryTwo;    
}
```

**3. ServiceOneIntegrationTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ComponentScan({"com.java.service","com.java.mapper"})
public class ServiceOneIntegrationTest {
```

**4. ServiceTwoIntegrationTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ComponentScan({"com.java.service","com.java.mapper"})
public class ServiceTwoIntegrationTest {
```

#### After fine-tuning the package names

**1. com.java.service.one.ServiceOneImpl**

```
@Service
public class ServiceOneImpl implements ServiceOne {   
  @Autowired
  private RepositoryOne repositoryOne;    
  @Autowired
  private ServiceTwo serviceTwo;      
  @Autowired
  private MapperOne mapperOne;
}
```

**2. com.java.service.two.ServiceTwoImpl**

```
@Service
public class ServiceTwoImpl implements ServiceTwo {   
  @Autowired
  private RepositoryTwo repositoryTwo;    
}
```

**3. ServiceOneIntegrationTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ComponentScan({"com.java.service","com.java.mapper"})
public class ServiceOneIntegrationTest {
```

**4. ServiceTwoIntegrationTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ComponentScan({"com.java.service.two"}) // CHANGE in the packages
public class ServiceTwoIntegrationTest {
```

Answer (score 0):

A unit test should test a component in isolation. You don`t even need to use the Spring Test context framework for a unit test. You can using mocking frameworks such as Mockito, JMock or EasyMock to isolate the dependencies in your component and verify the expectations.

If you want a true integration test then you need to use the @SpringBootTest annotation on your test class. If you dont specify the classes attribute it loads the @SpringBootApplication annotated class. This results in production components like db connections being loaded.

To eliminate these define a separate test configuration class which for example defines an embedded database instead of the production one

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public class ServiceFooTest{
}

@Configuration
@Import(SomeProductionConfiguration.class)
public class TestConfiguration{
   //test specific components
}
```