# How to autowire a bean in other class in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

In a Spring Boot application I have a class as below:

```
@Service
public class XYZ{
}
```

I want to use above in other class ABC like:

```
public class ABC{

    @Autowired
    private XYZ xyx;

}
```

It throws error that XYZ could not be found. I already have @SpringBootApplication in the class where the main method is written. Hence, this will automatically enable @ComponentScan on the package. ABC is created as a bean in spring configuration file. My understanding is, since XYZ has been annoted with @service, spring scans and creates and registers that bean. How can I access that bean in other class without using xml configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is `ABC` instantiated? The `ABC` object has to be instantiated by Spring.

In other words, the `ABC` class also has to be some sort of a `@Component`. It can be autowired by the `@SpringBootApplication` or in the case of web application, it can be a `@Controller`.

Comment: ABC is created as bean in spring configuration xml file

Comment: How are you using ABC after it was created as a bean?

Comment: ABC is event listener

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what `@Sharon Ben Asher` said above: Just in case if the error is thrown during a test execution and if the test context makes use of anything other than `@SpringBootTest`, then there is a chance for that context not to scan for @Service annotation beans.

For example, a test class annotated with `@DataJpaTest` won't scan for `@Service` beans; it requires an explicit `@ComponentScan` to parse it. Details on sample snippets could be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52939210/5107365.