# ContextConfiguration(classes=...) in Test doesn't scan packages specified in the Configuration class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have my application class defined as

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.binance.bot", "com.binance.api.client", "com.gateiobot"})
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class BinancebotApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
```

And in my springboot test I tried to use the auto scan packages by specifying the above Application class, as:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MACDCalculationIntegrationTest {
```

Test fails with

> Parameter 1 of constructor in com.gateiobot.macd.MACDCalculation required a bean of type 'com.binance.bot.common.Mailer' that could not be found.

Why isn't the autoscan working?

Comment: By default `@SpringBootApplication` has `@ComponentScan` , but can you explicitly define it ? `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.whatever"})` , by default it scans in base package where your application class is defined. Can you check if explicit definition helps ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why component scanning does not work for Spring Boot unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48679637/why-component-scanning-does-not-work-for-spring-boot-unit-tests)

Comment: @SpringBootTest(classes=BinancebotApplication.class) did it.